# Reset remaining leaves in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have tried to reset remaining leaves with out increment allocated leaves.
Ex:
1) Initially i have allocated 10 days legal leave for employee1.
2) Approved two days legal leave for employee1.

Now employee1 has 8 remaining out of 10 legal leaves. I need to add two days legal leave to employee1. result should be **(10 remaining out of 10).**

I have created a leave allocation of two days for this employee1.
The result is 10 remaining out of 12.
how can i resolve this.

I need to reset remaining leaves of all employees every year.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution, I don't know if it's correct method or not.

I have override the  `get_days` method in  `hr_holidays_status` model. Added below lines beginning of the function.

```
@api.multi
def get_days(self):
    currYear = date.today().year
    nextYear = date.today().year+1
    current_create_date = datetime.strptime(str(currYear)+'-01-01 00:00:00.000000',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    next_year_date = datetime.strptime(str(nextYear)+'-01-01 00:00:00.000000',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

    holidays = self.env['hr.holidays'].search([
        ('employee_id', '=', employee_id),
        ('state', 'in', ['confirm', 'validate1', 'validate']),
        ('holiday_status_id', 'in', self.ids),
        ('create_date','>=',current_create_date),
        ('create_date','<',next_year_date),
    ])
```

Please suggest me better solution if anybody have.